# update model attributes from view in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, model, controller

I have the following in my edit page for my `persons` view:

```
<%= form_for @person do |f| %>
    <%= label_tag :city %>
    <%= f.text_field :city %>
    <%= label_tag :state %>
    <%= f.text_field :state %>
    <%= label_tag :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

The idea is that I could update the `:city`, `:state`, and `:name` attributes on my `@person` model from this view.

What does my controller need to look like to make this happen? My route is passing through correctly, and in my controller I have this so far:

```
  def update
    @person = Person.find(params[:id])
    @person.update_attributes!(@person_params)
    redirect_to @person
  end
```

However, this just redirects my back to my show page for @person each time without actually updating the attributes on the model. What am I  missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should look something like this:

```
def update
  @person = Person.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @peron.update_attributes(params[:person])
      format.html { redirect_to people_url, notice: "#{@person.name} was updated." }
    else
      format.html { render action: "edit" }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this in your controller update action.

Passing the Person attributes as strong params.
This is the preferred method, as using strong params is recommended.

```
def update
    @person = Person.find(params[:id])
    @person.update(person_params)
    redirect_to @person
end
```

Make it a private method as:

```
private

def person_params
    params.require(:person).permit(:city, :state, :name)
end
```